# Can't connect containers mariadb and phpmyadmin

Tags: docker-compose, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I get the error "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory" when trying to login to phpmyadmin. I verified I can connect to the DB container from the localhost using mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p. Below is my docker-compose file:

```
    version: "3.7"
    ########################### SECRETS
    secrets:
      mysql_root_password:
        file: $DOCKERDIR/secrets/mysql_root_password
    
    ########################### SERVICES
    services:
    # Portainer - WebUI for Containers
      portainer:
        container_name: portainer
        image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
          - "$PORTAINER_PORT:9000"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
          - $DOCKERDIR/portainer/data:/data
        environment:
          - TZ=$TZ
    
     # MariaDB - MySQL Database
      db:
        container_name: db
        image: linuxserver/mariadb:latest
        restart: always
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
          - "$MARIADB_PORT:3306"
        volumes:
          - $DOCKERDIR/mariadb/data:/config
        environment:
          - PUID=$PUID
          - PGID=$PGID
          - TZ=$TZ
          - FILE__MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
        secrets:
          - mysql_root_password
    
    # phpMyAdmin - Database management
      phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
          - db
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
          - "$PHPMYADMIN_PORT:80"
        volumes:
          - $DOCKERDIR/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=db
          #- PMA_ARBITRARY=1
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
        secrets:
          - mysql_root_password
    
    # Dozzle - Real-time Docker Log Viewer
      dozzle:
        image: amir20/dozzle:latest
        container_name: dozzle
        restart: unless-stopped
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
          - "$DOZZLE_PORT:8080"
        environment:
          DOZZLE_LEVEL: info
          DOZZLE_TAILSIZE: 300
          DOZZLE_FILTER: "status=running"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong to log into Phpmyadmin. Can someone explain my mistake or mistakes and point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out, first was I had the network set on the pphpmyadmin section, and not db, once I added the network statement to db section, I was able to connect.